# C++ two or more data types in declaration

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I'm getting a strange error from `g++` 3.3 in the following code:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <int N, int M>
bitset<N> slice_bitset(const bitset<M> &original, size_t start) {
    string str = original.to_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >();
    string newstr = str.substr(start, N);
    return bitset<N>(newstr);
}

int main() {
    bitset<128> test;
    bitset<12> result = slice_bitset<12, 128>(test, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
In function `std::bitset slice_bitset(const std::bitset&, unsigned int)':
syntax error before `,' token
`char_traits' specified as declarator-id
two or more data types in declaration of `char_traits'
`allocator' specified as declarator-id
two or more data types in declaration of `allocator'
syntax error before `>' token
```

It has to be something really silly, but I've already told it to my rubber duck and a friend to no avail.

Thanks, Lazyweb.

Comment: +1 for telling it to your rubber duck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The selected answer from [CAdaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231868/c-two-or-more-data-types-in-declaration#231904) solves the problem, but does not explain **why** it solves the problem.

When a function template is being parsed, lookup does not take place in dependent types.  As a result, constructs such as the following can be parsed:

```
template <typename T>
class B;

template <typename T>
void foo (B<T> & b) {
  // Use 'b' here, even though 'B' not defined
}

template <typename T>
class B
{
  // Define 'B' here.
};
```

However, this "feature" has a cost, and in this case it is that the definition of 'foo' requires hints on the contents of the template 'B'.  If 'foo' uses a nested type of 'B', then the `typename` keyword is required to tell the compiler that the name is a type:

```
template <typename T>
void foo (B<T> & b)
{
  typename B<T>::X t1;    // 'X' is a type - this declares t1
  B<T>::Y * t1;           // 'Y' is an object - this is multiplication
}
```

Without 'typename' in the above the compiler will assume that `X` is an object (or function).

Similarly, if a member function is called and the call has explicit template arguments then the compiler needs to know to treat the `<` as the start of a template argument list and not the less than operator:

```
template <typename T>
void foo (B<T> & b)
{
  b.template bar<int> (0); // 'bar' is a template, '<' is start of arg list
  b.Y < 10;                // 'Y' is an object, '<' is less than operator
}
```

Without `template`, the compiler assumes that `<` is the less than operator, and so generates the syntax error when it sees `int>` since that is not an expression.

These hints are required *even* when the definition of the template is visible.  The reason is that an explicit specialization might later change the definition that is actually chosen:

```
template <typename T>
class B
{
  template <typename S>
  void a();
};

template <typename T>
void foo (B<T> & b)
{
  b.a < 10;            // 'B<int>::a' is a member object
}

template <>
class B<int>
{
  int a;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

Use either just

```
original.to_string();
```

or, if you really need the type specifiers,

```
original.template to_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >();
```

Comment: The to_string has no default specification in this case, but your latter answer works! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following compiled for me (using gcc 3.4.4):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <int N, int M> 
bitset<N> slice_bitset(const bitset<M> &original, size_t start) 
{   
  string str = original.to_string();
  string newstr = str.substr(start, N);    
  return bitset<N>(newstr);
}

int main() 
{ 
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but it won't compile if you actually call the function and evaluate the template parameters.

Comment: Adding #include <iostream> and changing main to this compiled (with gcc 4.0.1):

int main()
{
 bitset<4> orig;
 orig.set(0,0);
 orig.set(1,1);
 orig.set(2,0);
 orig.set(3,1);
 bitset<2> bits = slice_bitset<2,4>(orig, 2);
 cout << bits.to_string() << endl;
 return 0;
}

What error are you getting?

Comment: I get the same error as above. I am using g++ 3.3, however -- they may have updated the stdlib in g++ to include a default template parameter in 3.4, but cplusplus.com says "they are not implicitly deduced by the compiler." (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/to_string.html)